# Zend Captcha with custom character set

Tags: zend-framework, captcha

I sucsessfully use captcha in forms but now my problem is to make captcha contains digits only. I found that the symbols in captcha image are generated in `generateWord` method of `Zend/Captcha/Word.php` class.
I'd like to preset new array of character to use (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0), but I shouldn't change library code because it's used in other projects and for future updates.
How to set up custom captcha code clearly?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What stops you from extending `Zend_Captcha_Word` class ?

Quick-and-dirty way, before you generate captcha set all symbols to digits:

```
Zend_Captcha_Word::$CN = Zend_Captcha_Word::$C = Zend_Captcha_Word::$VN = Zend_Captcha_Word::$V = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
```

Comment: I know it's too late. This helped. I extended `Zend_Captcha_Word` class and added my own symbols array.

Answer (score 0):

As per link below

[link](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/zendframework/zf2/class-Zend.Captcha.AbstractWord.html)

it is not possible without change in library to make captcha which contains only letters you must be change in array as describe in above link to make only numbers

let me know if i can assist you more..